# Find all sql files using bat

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop, dos

How to find all the sql files inside a folder and get the file names using a batch file?
I have tried like:

> for /f %%a IN (‘dir "C:\SQLFILES\
>   *.sql"’) do echo %%a

But I am not getting the proper output.

Comment: What output *are* you getting?

Comment: I need to pass the file name to another bat file like:  for /f %%a IN (‘dir "C:\SQLFILES\ *.sql"’) do test.bat %%a.But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for %%a in (*.sql) do echo %%a`

or

`for %%a in (c:\sqlfiles\*.sql) do echo %%a`

Just read your update. To call another batch file you need:

`for %%a in (c:\sqlfiles\*.sql) do call myotherbatch.cmd %%a`

If you don't `call` the batch file then control will be transferred over for good, there won't be a return from the child script.

Also, batch files are now `.cmd` files. `.bat` is legacy.

Comment: For the vast majority of batch files the extension does not matter. I tend to use `cmd` out of habit, but `bat` won't make a difference usually.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
cd C:SQLFILES
dir /b /s *.sql
```